# What type of sheathed wires to use for 240V without neutral?

Tags: electrical, 240v

I am looking at two different circuits 1) for an oven and 2) for a radiant heat system. Both 240V. The oven circuit requires a neutral, while radiant heat circuit does not.

For the oven, I use a #6/3 wire.
For the radiant heat system, #10/2 (no neutral).

Questions:

1. Is there a sheathed wire with red, black, ground but no neutral at 10AWG?
2. or is 10/3 used and the neutral connected to the ground?
3. If neutral is connected to the ground, are there any specific requirements to connect Neutral to Ground?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sheathed cables you're allowed to paint the white wire black or red at both ends of each stretch and pretend that it's that color all the way inside the sheath.

Tape, heat-shrink sleeving, sharpie, etc are also allowed instead of paint - anything "effective",  you don't have to paint the whole exposed part of the white wire, just enough that it is a clear marking)

> 200.7 Use of Insulation of a White or Gray Color or with Three Continuous White or Gray Stripes
> (C) Circuits of 50 Volts or More.

> The use of insulation that is white or gray or that has three continuous white or gray stripes for other than a grounded conductor for circuits of 50 volts or more shall be permitted only as in (1) and (2).

> (1) If part of a cable assembly that has the insulation permanently reidentified to indicate its use as an ungrounded conductor by marking tape, painting, or other effective means at its termination and at each location where the conductor is visible and accessible. Identification shall encircle the insulation and shall be a color other than white, gray, or green. If used for single-pole, 3-way or 4-way switch loops, the reidentified conductor with white or gray insulation or three continuous white or gray stripes shall be used only for the supply to the switch, but not as a return conductor from the switch to the outlet.

So for a circuit with no neutral you can just mark up a 2-and-earth cable and use that.

Comment: Re-marking the white wire to black or red is mandatory.

Comment: actually several other colors are allowed, basically just not white grey or green.  I was taking as given that  white wires are not allowed for non-neutral conductors. except for this carve-out.